# Paho Javascript Mqtt Client (Over Websockets) is not connecting to Mosquitto Broker (hosted on Google Cloud VM)

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I installed Mosquitto on a VM referring the following link
https://gist.github.com/smoofit/dafa493aec8d41ea057370dbfde3f3fc

The Mosquitto Broker is Up and shows

```
1565283316: mosquitto version 1.4.12 (build date 2019-08-08 15:47:50+0000) starting
1565283316: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1565283316: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1565283316: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1565283316: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

But not able to connect from the Paho Javascript Client

I tried installing the newest version of Mqtt with mosquitto. I allowed 9001 and 1883 ports on firewall but not able to connect.

Here is my JS Client Code.

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script>
// Create a client instance
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(IPAddress, Number(9001), "clientId");

// set callback handlers
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});


// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("World");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "World";
  client.send(message);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What if any errors are you getting in browser console. And what if anything is added to the mosquitto logs when you try to connect. (also it might be useful to actually see your mosquitto.conf file). Also there should be no need to the `Number()` wrapper in the connection string.

Comment: Browser Console I get  WebSocket connection to 'ws://ipaddress:9001/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Please edit the question when adding details, but that error implies you haven't opened the ports properly

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and can you please help me where can I see ports have been properly opened or not.

Comment: No idea, I've never used Google Cloud VMs